# How to talk about the content of something?

Tags: grammar

How would you explain the content of a book, movie, document, etc. to someone else in Japanese? A is about B. Like "This book is about two girls falling in love" and "That movie is about a ninja who has to fight a dragon to save his parents". Everything I come up with seems extremely clunky and I would like some help.

Some attempts

> この本の内容は二人女の子が惚れる。
>
> この本について二人女の子が惚れる。

Answer (score 1):

```
   ( Ok, maybe it wasn't a "translation request". )
```

---- By searching with these keywords, you can get more variations.

この本は、女の子２人が恋に落ちる話です。
この本は、女の子２人が恋をするストーリーです。
この本では、女の子２人が恋をするんです。
この本では、女の子２人が　・・・をしちゃうんです。

この映画の主題は・・・です。
これは、・・・が主題（テーマ）の映画です。
これは、・・・を追求した映画です。

これは、「もしも男女２人の体と心が入れ替わったらどうなる？」　という映画です。
これは、・・・が・・・して、・・・する映画です。
これは、・・・が・・・して、・・・するという映画です。

この映画の見せ場 （見所、クライマックス） は、・・・の場面です。
この映画のメインは、・・・という展開です。
この映画のさわりは、・・・の場面です。

> nihongo.koakishiki.com/goi/question-30.html
>   「話のさわり」というときの「さわり」は、浄瑠璃用語で　「曲中で最も聞きどころ、聞かせどころとされている部分」を指します。 　それが転じて、「話の中心となる部分、聞かせどころ」、「演劇・映画などの名場面、見どころ」を意味するようになりました。 　よく、「物話の導入部、最初の部分」という意味で用いられますがそれは本来の意味ではありません。 ...

Answer (score 0):

I like your first translation but you could add 話 at the end to make it a bit better :).

> この本の内容は二人の女の子が惚れるという話です。

or

> その映画は二人の女の子が恋に落ちる話です。

Comment: 一文目・・・`二人女の子が`　←　「の」が抜けてないですか？ でも「惚れるという話」ってちょっと意味がよくわかんないですね。。（「惚れる話です」って言われると、「誰に？」って思うんで。。）「二人の女の子が悪魔に惚れる話です」とかならわかる気がしますが・・「二人の女の子が恋をするお話です」とか・・

Comment: @chocolate そうですね。OPの気持をそのままにしようかなーと思ってw